# Make a content visible when mouseover on 1/3 width of container without adding subcontainers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have div container with width 100%. I need to make a content hide and show according to mouse over in container. But this will need to happen with 30% from left of main container and rest(70%) with no show/hide effect. Can we make this effect without adding any additional sub containers?

An Image representation
[image: An image]

How to make this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWu4u/2/) illustrates a very basic solution; it calls the effect every time the mouse moves inside the 30%, so you might need to add some further logic to prevent that happening.

I've used a container of 500px width, and a subcontainer div, but only for illustrative purposes; the JavaScript will manage a single container of any width. You'll need to add any positioning, margin or padding to the 'widthModifier' variable, but you could get those from the container in JavaScript too, if you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's answer doesn't solve the problem showing and hiding the content. Take a look at my [solution](http://jsfiddle.net/E5v4d/1/) that does exactly what you want. I used CSS features to achieve the result.

Use Chrome to view the example. For other browsers you just have to add their specific implementations of the css features.